# Lubuntu 14.04 boot errors

Tags: boot, kernel, lubuntu

I'm trying to run lubuntu 14.04 (i386) on a old computer. I set up a bootable usb drive. 
After I choose to run lubuntu "without instalation" I get these errors:

```
02064241 pci 0000:00:Oa* BAR 4: error updating (high 040000c 1--;
0400: 
9.5880661 *** EEPROM MAC address is invalid. 
9.5881351 3c59x: vortex_probe1 fails. Returns -22 
10.932317 sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching node page found 
10.932387 sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] AssuNing drive cache: write through 
10.977068 mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 0 Bank 0: a200000084010400
10.977129 mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0, 
10.977241 mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:f34 TIME 1424688627 SOCKET 0 A PIC 0 microcode 13 
10.977305 mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii' 
10.977369 mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 4 Bank 0: b20000001040080f 
10.977433 mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 00:<00000000clObbe60> 
10.977546 mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 3c5ebd49f7 
10.977657 mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:f34 TIME 1424688638 SOCKET 0 A PIC 0 microcode 13
10.977719 mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii' 
10.977779 mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check: Processor context corrupt 
10.977841 Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal Machine check
10.977909 Kernel Offset: Ox0 from Oxcl000000 (relocation range: Oxc0000000-Oxf7ffdffn 
10.977982 Rebooting in 30 seconds..
```

After the error the computer reboots. I have no access to terminal or anything else. I've already tried with lubuntu 14.10, arch linux and puppy linux. I tried ultimate boot cd and it gives me the same error when I try to run CPUstress.

I would be tempted to guess that it's a cpu problem but the thing is that windows xp is installed on the computer and I can boot to it.

I've tested the memory with memtest86 (from the lubuntu live usb) and it passed without errors

Specs:
Intel Celeron D 2.4
1GB ram (2x512MB)
HDD 80GB